# Spring @Transactional rollbackFor not working for checked Exception for method called outside proxy object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, annotations

I am having a problem with the rollback of Hibernate updates in combination with Spring.

I have the following class:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DocumentServiceImpl extends AbstractGenericService<Document, IDocumentDao> implements DocumentService {

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=false, rollbackFor = DocumentServiceException.class)
    public void saveDocument(final DocumentForm form, final BindingResult result, final CustomUserContext userContext) throws DocumentServiceException {
        Document document = locateDocument(form, userContext);
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            try {
                updateDocumentCategories(form, document);
                storeDocument(document, form.getDocumentId(), form.getFile());
                solrService.addDocument(document);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                result.reject("error.uploading.file");
                throw new DocumentServiceException("Error trying to copy the uploaded file to its final destination", e);
            } catch (SolrServerException e) {
                result.reject("error.uploading.file.solr");
                throw new DocumentServiceException("Solr had an error parsing your uploaded file", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = IOException.class)
    public void storeDocument(Document document, String documentId, CommonsMultipartFile uploadedFile) throws IOException {
        getDao().saveOrUpdate(document);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(documentId)) {
            File newFile = documentLocator.createFile(document);
            uploadedFile.transferTo(newFile);
            // Todo: TEST FOR ROLLBACK ON FILE I/O EXCEPTION
            throw new IOException("this is a test");
        }
    }
```

The interface is not tagged with any @Transactional annotations. The saveDocument() method is called directly from my Controller, so I expect that the @Transactional configuration of that method is used, particularly the rollbackFor parameter. However, when the DocumentServiceException is thrown, nothing is rolled back (ie the getDao().saveOrUpdate(document) is persisted). For testing purposes I added an "throw new IOException" in the storeDocument method. Hope anybody can help me out how to get this working, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `@Transactional` annotation on `storeDocument` is useless as it is an internal method call, only calls into a proxy have AOP applied. If there is no rollback I suspect you have something wrong in your setup and no transactions are actually applied. Another thing is that it is a bit strange, imho, to have your `BindingResult` and next to that have it tied to the web (you are directly using `CommonsMultipartFile` which is web related). Basically your service layer is now dependent on the web...

Comment: Enable spring logs to verify if transactions are getting started

Comment: @"M. Deinum".. the storeDocument method is also separately called by other controllers, so for that we need the @ Transactional annotation. I am aware that it is useless if called indirectly.

Comment: @Andy transactions work.. I did another test by throwing a RuntimeException (instead of IOException), and in that case it rolls back the saveOrUpdate commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The @Transactional annotation is properly placed. You don;t have to set it at interface level, because it's not automatically inherited (what if your concrete class implements two interfaces with a conflicting transactional setting).
2. When you say the method are called directly, I assume you have the interface being @Autowired and not the concrete implementation.
3. Place a break point in your service method and check if your have a TransactionInterceptor entry in your stack trace. If you don't have it, then your transaction management configuration is wrong and you are not using Spring transaction management at all.

### Update from Dennis

1. One more thing that could help other people perhaps:

   I had the tx:annotation-driven in my applicationContext. The applicationContext contained a component-scan for all beans (no filters).

   However, the dispatcherServlet context also contained a component-scan for all beans (legacy code, don't shoot the messenger). So basically I had a copy of all my beans because they were scanned in both contexts.

   And because the beans created in the dispatcherServlet context did not contain the tx:annotation-driven element, the services beans in the dispatcherServlet context were not transactional.
2. I had to change the component-scan in the dispatcherServlet context into:

   ```
   <context:component-scan base-package="your/base/package" use-default-filters="false">    
       <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/> 
   </context:component-scan>
   ```

   So, it will only instantiate the controllers in the dispatcher servlet context (and no autowired dependencies, like its services), and the services/daos in the applicationContext.

The services from the applicationContext are then transactionalized.

Comment: darn, you're right with point 3.. I don't see a TransactionInterceptor. I guess something else (container?) is rolling back changes when a RuntimeException is detected?

Comment: If there's no TransactionInterceptor you're simply using auto-commit, so every statement goes in its own transaction. So if you have 5 statements and 4 work and the last one fails, you will still see the first 4 statements persisted while it's only the last one that's roll-backed.

Comment: Not sure about that.. If I throw a RuntimeException AFTER I save a record using Hibernate, the record is rolled back.. So the transaction scope must be larger than what you suggest?

Comment: It also depends on db connection management. If all queries see the same connection and there is no auto commit then you practically have a transaction. I think it calls for a debug.

Comment: One more thing that could help other people perhaps: I had the tx:annotation-driven in my applicationContext. The applicationContext contained a component-scan for all beans (no filters). However, the dispatcherServlet context also contained a component-scan for all beans (legacy code, don't shoot the messenger). So basically I had a copy of all my beans because they were scanned in both contexts. And because the beans created in the dispatcherServlet context did not contain the tx:annotation-driven element, the services beans in the dispatcherServlet context were not transactional.

Comment: I had to change the component-scan in the dispatcherServlet context into: 

    `<context:component-scan base-package="your/base/package" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>`

so, it will only instantiate the controllers in the dispatcher servlet context (and no autowired dependencies, like its services), and the services/daos in the applicationContext. The services from the applicationContext are then transactionalized.

Comment: Ok, I will add them in the answer.

Comment: Hi Vlad, I would but I am not allowed since I am a noobie / don't have enough pts ;)